# replace() method not replacing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace some hex code in a string. this is the string I have:

```
 "https://r4---sn-p5qlsnsy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=clen%2Cdur%252Cei%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%26ipbits=0%26requiressl=yes%26signature=6F1247213581BAB17D93BEB155E51A87FE273272.98CCB77419DD3369BFBD4024E045FA02CF37EA53%26mime=video%252F3gpp%26initcwndbps%3D3172500%26c%3DWEB%26pl%3D21%26ei%3D0njrWqGQKYiF8wSJoaiABw%26clen%3D5078833%26itag%3D36%26gir%3Dyes%26mt%3D1525381200%26mn%3Dsn-p5qlsnsy%252Csn-vgqs7ney%26mm%3D31%252C26%26id%3Do-AMFAbDddd4Dd83KwkSZ0Q0BRT-lADdhBUSTA-ZwdlKhg%26dur%3D185.341%26lmt%3D1511566272128708%26ip%3D54.81.171.42%26key%3Dyt6%26fexp%3D23724337%26mv%3Dm%26expire%3D1525402930%26source%3Dyoutube%26fvip%3D4%26ms%3Dau%252Conr&type=video/3gpp;+codecs%3D=mp4v.20.3%2C+mp4a.40.2%22,quality=small&itag=17%"
```

I'm trying to replace "%3D" with "=", but it's not working.

```
 b = "https://r4---sn-p5qlsnsy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=clen%2Cdur%252Cei%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%26ipbits=0%26requiressl=yes%26signature=6F1247213581BAB17D93BEB155E51A87FE273272.98CCB77419DD3369BFBD4024E045FA02CF37EA53%26mime=video%252F3gpp%26initcwndbps%3D3172500%26c%3DWEB%26pl%3D21%26ei%3D0njrWqGQKYiF8wSJoaiABw%26clen%3D5078833%26itag%3D36%26gir%3Dyes%26mt%3D1525381200%26mn%3Dsn-p5qlsnsy%252Csn-vgqs7ney%26mm%3D31%252C26%26id%3Do-AMFAbDddd4Dd83KwkSZ0Q0BRT-lADdhBUSTA-ZwdlKhg%26dur%3D185.341%26lmt%3D1511566272128708%26ip%3D54.81.171.42%26key%3Dyt6%26fexp%3D23724337%26mv%3Dm%26expire%3D1525402930%26source%3Dyoutube%26fvip%3D4%26ms%3Dau%252Conr&type=video/3gpp;+codecs%3D=mp4v.20.3%2C+mp4a.40.2%22,quality=small&itag=17%"
 b = b.replace("%3D", "=")
```

I'm using Google Chrome in Windows 10

Comment: Are you not getting errors? Your `b` variable should probably be a string?

Comment: if you'd wrap that url with `'url'` it will replace

Comment: Use `decodeURIComponent` to decode url encode

Comment: My variable was a string, for some reason I removed them when I pasted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `""` for string initialization, and also use global replace to replace all comparators `/%3D/g`:

```js
b = "https://r4---sn-p5qlsnsy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=clen%2Cdur%252Cei%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%26ipbits=0%26requiressl=yes%26signature=6F1247213581BAB17D93BEB155E51A87FE273272.98CCB77419DD3369BFBD4024E045FA02CF37EA53%26mime=video%252F3gpp%26initcwndbps%3D3172500%26c%3DWEB%26pl%3D21%26ei%3D0njrWqGQKYiF8wSJoaiABw%26clen%3D5078833%26itag%3D36%26gir%3Dyes%26mt%3D1525381200%26mn%3Dsn-p5qlsnsy%252Csn-vgqs7ney%26mm%3D31%252C26%26id%3Do-AMFAbDddd4Dd83KwkSZ0Q0BRT-lADdhBUSTA-ZwdlKhg%26dur%3D185.341%26lmt%3D1511566272128708%26ip%3D54.81.171.42%26key%3Dyt6%26fexp%3D23724337%26mv%3Dm%26expire%3D1525402930%26source%3Dyoutube%26fvip%3D4%26ms%3Dau%252Conr&type=video/3gpp;+codecs%3D=mp4v.20.3%2C+mp4a.40.2%22,quality=small&itag=17%";
     b = b.replace(/%3D/g, "=");

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to surround the value that you have assigned to `b` with quotes.

```
b = "https://r4---sn-p5qlsnsy.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=clen%2Cdur%252Cei%252Cgir%252Cid%252Cinitcwndbps%252Cip%252Cipbits%252Citag%252Clmt%252Cmime%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cpl%252Crequiressl%252Csource%252Cexpire%26ipbits=0%26requiressl=yes%26signature=6F1247213581BAB17D93BEB155E51A87FE273272.98CCB77419DD3369BFBD4024E045FA02CF37EA53%26mime=video%252F3gpp%26initcwndbps%3D3172500%26c%3DWEB%26pl%3D21%26ei%3D0njrWqGQKYiF8wSJoaiABw%26clen%3D5078833%26itag%3D36%26gir%3Dyes%26mt%3D1525381200%26mn%3Dsn-p5qlsnsy%252Csn-vgqs7ney%26mm%3D31%252C26%26id%3Do-AMFAbDddd4Dd83KwkSZ0Q0BRT-lADdhBUSTA-ZwdlKhg%26dur%3D185.341%26lmt%3D1511566272128708%26ip%3D54.81.171.42%26key%3Dyt6%26fexp%3D23724337%26mv%3Dm%26expire%3D1525402930%26source%3Dyoutube%26fvip%3D4%26ms%3Dau%252Conr&type=video/3gpp;+codecs%3D=mp4v.20.3%2C+mp4a.40.2%22,quality=small&itag=17%";
```